# How to make 100% width form with bootstrap?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make 3 form boxes to be inline with each other but have a width of 100% (but be able to specify the width of each section, or even better, have the last two form sections be their automatic/standard size and make the first section fill the rest of the space).

Currently I have:

```
<div class="row">
 <form class="form-inline" role="form" name="input" action="LINK_HERE" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="sr-only" for="lg_query">Label</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="query" id="lg_query" placeholder="Placeholder" autofocus="autofocus" value="VALUE" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label class="sr-only" for="SOMEID">text</label>
   <select class="form-control">
    <option value="1">se</option>
    <option value="3" selected>ros</option>
    <option value="14">rds</option>
    <option value="4">sbh</option>
    <option value="7">sc</option>
    <option value="8">rcs</option>
    <option value="9">rns</option>
    <option value="10">rws</option>
    <option value="12">rps</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="module1"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit</button>
 </form>   
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zSb22/

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Thanks so much @isherwood for adding the jsfiddle! I wasn't aware of how to add the bootstrap and jQuery stuff using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual approach is to simply use Bootstrap's grid:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zSb22/3

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
```

Here's an example with better block layout and width variations:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/zSb22/4

Comment: Perfect! Your second link (version 4) was exactly what I needed! Thank you very much. Now to implement it and tidy up for different device widths. :)